# How can I make an $ionicPopup only appear one time then never again?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use $ionicPopup as a quick tutorial screen when a user first logs in. After they log in they never need to see the message again. I haven't been able to find any examples on how to do this in Ionic Framework.

Here is the code I have so far where I place it inside a $timeout function() so that I can set a timeout.

$timeout(function(){
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

```
  template: '<h4 class="ion-ios-search-strong"> Choose a store</h4></br><h4 class="ion-coffee"> Select a drink</h4></br><h4 class="ion-wrench"> Customize your coffee</h4></br><h4 class="ion-card"> Pay from your phone</h4></br><h4 class="ion-happy-outline"> Your coffee is ready</h4></br>',
     title: 'How to use Joe',
     // subTitle: 'Your coffee is a few taps away',
     scope: $scope,

      buttons: [
           { text: 'Got it!' },
       ]
 });   

myPopup.then(function(res) {
   console.log('Tapped!', res);
});
```

},5000);

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- Set a variable `firstTime` to `true` when the user logs in.
- Check to see if `firstTime` is `true` before calling `$ionicPopup.show`.
- Set `firstTime` to `false` after the check to see if it's `true`.
- You can store `firstTime` in an Angular service if you have no where else to store it.  If you want the value of `firstTime` to persist even if the user refreshes, you can store it in `localStorage`.  For example, check out [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

Comment: or you can store firstTime in localstorage and check from there

Comment: this wouldn't be persistent and firstTime would always be false whenever app launches. Using localStorage as @Antonis suggested is one way to go